# How to stop animation flickering

Tags: codenameone

Are there some generic techniques for stopping the display flickering? I'm guessing that I have two layout animations that are fighting over the controls or something - this seems to happen in a few places in my app (hence the general question).

I'll try and be more specific too:
I have a `Box Layout Y` `Container` which contains a list of `MultiButton`s. The MultiButtons are my own class which inherits MultiButton. It (all the buttons) flicks when I come back to the `Form` from another form. In the beforeForm function I do this:

```
for (my loop)
{
MultiButton mb = new MultiButton();
...init code for mb, like setTextLine1();
container.addComponent(mb);
lastMb = mb;
}
container.revalidate();
container.scrollComponentToVisible(lastMb);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeForm` method is invoked before the form is shown so there is no need to revalidate at that stage (show implicitly does that).

What's `scrollToComponent`? If you remove it does it flicker?

To scroll to a component without an animation do:

```
container.setSmoothScrolling(false);
container.scrollComponentToVisible(cmp);
container.setSmoothScrolling(true);
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I typed that wrong: scrollComponenttoVisible. I put the revalidate in originally because if I don't the scrollcompoonentToVisble has no effect.

Comment: I've got it to work by doing what you've suggested, but I have to put it in a callSerially or it doesn't scroll. If I call it serially with smooth scrolling on then it works but leaves the blue end-of-scroll highlight visible permanently. All seems a bit hacky. What would you do?

Comment: I think this might be resolved by moving the last bit of code to the postForm method. During the before method the components aren't laid out yet so scroll to visible essentially scrolls to a component at the default 0,0. If you move just the scrolling portion to the post method it will execute after show() when the components are laid out.

Comment: OK. postForm does resolve that flicker. I've removed another revalidate which I think caused a different one (time will tell).

I still have another one where I have a form with a TextArea and a Button. Often, when I press the button whilst the TextArea has the focus the keyboard disappearing seems to create a funny background flicker - as I press the button the background goes black and when I release it returns to normal (again, on Android) - it keeps doing it every time I press the button.

Comment: Video of it on sendspace: [video of flickering background](http://www.sendspace.com/file/6cqs5x)

Comment: Are you using the async paint build flag?

Comment: I haven't change any build flags. Do you mean the build hints?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be related to your component, what are you doing in that component?

Comment: The Form in the video is not the one with the custom multibutton of the question above. The Form in the video is just standard controls (TextArea, Label, Button (with icon), and Picker (with strings of numbers). When I press the button I change the "pressed icon" so that it's different on the next press. I've tried pushing that into callSerially, but it still did the flicky thing you can see.

Comment: I've just done another test: create a new codenameone app using the tabbed template. In the about box I've added a textarea and a button. I can reproduce the same effect as seen in the video. Again, you can only see this on Android, not the emulator. Can send you the project if you like.

Comment: File an issue with the test case project in the issue tracker, it allows you to attach files http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/

Comment: I have [raised the issue, here](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=1087). I can repeat the same thing with a basically empty app and with the kitchen sink demo. It's quite a serious one in that every app with a text field flicks. Just so you know.

Comment: We'll look into this, I use Android as my personal device and so do quite a few of my colleagues. We don't experience any such flickering.

Comment: Odd! Well if there's anything I can do to help let me know.